# Parse yml file with yq when multiple keys are not nested (i.e abc.def)

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yml file that looks like:

```
abc.def:
  key: value
```

and I am trying to get the value of key by doing the following:

```
yq '.abc.def.key' file.yml
```

but it is returning null.
If I format the yml file as:

```
abc:
  def:
    key: value
```

the yq command returns value.
I need to be able to parse both versions and I cant just manually update the yml files.  Is there something I am missing? Is there a format command I can preprocess the file with so yq will work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two YAML documents are **NOT** two "versions" or representations of the same data, they are actually two very different files. One has a key that happens to include a dot, the other one has one level more of nesting. Again, this is not another version of the same document.

To address a key with special characters (like a dot), use the universal syntax for addressing keys: `.["abc.def"]` or `."abc.def"`. Dropping (brackets and) quotes is just a shortcut for keys that do not contain special characters (as with `.key`): `.["abc.def"].key` or `."abc.def".key`

> I need to be able to parse both versions

You can use the alternative operator `//` to address another path if the first one evaluates to `null` or `false`:

```bash
yq '(.["abc.def"] // .abc.def).key'
```

This works with both [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) and [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). (Tested with kislyuk/yq 3.2.3 and mikefarah/yq v4.35.1).

---

Alternatively, if you want to regard both documents as equivalent, you could just transform one into the other, i.e. expand paths with dots in a key name to the nested variant (note that collisions might occur), and then just query the unified version using the simple syntax, e.g. `.abc.def.key`.

Here's how you'd convert with kislyuk/yq using `tostream` to recursively get paths and values, and `reduce` to iteratively re-build the output object:

```bash
reduce (tostream | select(has(1)) | first |= map(split(".")[]))
  as [$p,$v] (null; setpath($p; $v))
```

And here's the same with mikefarah/yq using `..` to traverse, `path` to get the path, and `ireduce` for the build-up:

```bash
[ ..
  | select(tag != "!!map" and tag != "!!seq")
  | [[path | .[] | split(".") | .[]], .]
] | .[] as $p ireduce (null; setpath($p[0]; $p[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Worked perfectly.